# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in Errors

Tags: php, arrays, json

identifier, code, type... I can handle operations with foreach. Lakin, I want to take part odds, unfortunately I get a  " Object of class stdClass could not be error.

Comment: Where's the code where you're trying to use it?

Comment: `foreach($json as $row){
 if(isset($row->odds)){
  echo $row->odds;
 }
 echo "<br><br>";
}`

Comment: You need to access `$object[0]->odds->{"SC.GG"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`odds` is an object, not a string or number, so you can't echo it. You need to access the `SC.GG` property.

```
foreach($json as $row){ 
    if(isset($row->odds)){ 
        echo $row->odds->{"SC.CG"}; 
    } 
    echo "<br><br>"; 
}
```